# Grouping a dataframe by year to plot smaller diagrams

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have some daily values that spread over 10 years.

Date, Temp

"1981-01-01",20.7
"1981-01-02",17.9
...
"1990-12-31",13.0

I'm reading these values from a csv into a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'.\data\daily-minimum-temperatures.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I would like to group all these values by year to plot 10 line diagrams (one per year) in order to compare them.

I tried to use Grouper like this

```
grouper = df.groupby(['Date', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='Y')])
```

I get the grouper object (DataFrameGroupBy) with a length of 10. I understand that this object represents my data grouped in ten years.

But when trying to plot this object, I get an error.

```
grouper.plot()
RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: As far as I can tell you are already doing it. What is the problem?

Comment: You want a series per year.?

Comment: My problem is that I have no idea what I can do with "grouper". This object is a DataFrameGroupBy type, and I do not know how I can handle it. Can I enumerate it ? Is it something like a DataFrame ?

Comment: Ok, I've found what I was looking for : it is the DataFrameGroupBy get_group method !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare the actual variation of the values per year with a line plot, rather than grouping the dataframe, you can just loop over the years in dataframe to select year by year and make a plot for that.

In codes,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

toy = pd.DataFrame()

toy['Time'] = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('1981-01-01'), end=pd.Timestamp('1990-12-31'), freq='1D')
toy['Values'] = np.random.random_sample((len(toy)))

years = sorted(np.unique(toy['Time'].dt.year))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 18))

for i in range(len(years)):

    sliced = toy.loc[toy.Time.dt.year == years[i]]

    x = sliced['Time']
    y = sliced['Values']

    plt.subplot(len(years), 1, i+1)
    plt.plot(x, y, '-')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Value')


plt.show()
```

[image: Output plot]